# Margin/ Alignment in firefox/safari which fix do i use and how?

Tags: css

the navigation bar in ** works fine in safari, however firefox is being a bit of a pain. I can see a small margin/padding difference between the two browsers, however can't quite work out why. any ideas?

EDIT: Don't worry figured it out.

font used was not rendered the same in both browsers!

Comment: They look just the same for me, just the menu jumping in firefox because text wont fit its container. But that's not a padding issue, it's just that browsers render the text differently, you can't make text to be rendered the same in every browser, so you'd have to change the `nav ul li a`'s padding to something like `padding: 0 42px 0 46px;`.

Comment: thanks, just realised, guess i'm having a slow day!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple font rendering issue, due to -webkit-font-smoothing, note to self; check that out next time!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mozilla hack (generally not advisable) and add Margin and Padding properties. It is recommended that you install Firebug in Mozilla. You can change your CSS on the fly and in your file accordingly.